# Hiddent parameters in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have this redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = viewModel.IsWizard });
```

And this is the signature of the method `ProductionOrderController.Index`:

```
// GET: ProductionOrder
public ActionResult Index(bool isWizard = false)
```

When I call this method on my web browser I get this URL:

```
http://VANSFANNEL:53827/ProductionOrder?isWizard=True
```

Is there a way to hidden the parameter `isWizard` and don't show it in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. A redirect is always an HTTP GET, so you can't POST the parameter which kind-of hides it.

I don't know your exact requirements, but if you can rewrite the code to become a POST, that would be the easiest way to remove the parameter from the URL. Else you might want to save it somewhere else: in a session variable or obfuscate the value so you can de-hash it later on.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, what you really should be doing is return a view rather than redirect.

Like:

```
return View(viewModel);
```

But if you really prefer to do a redirect, you can place the ViewModel in the TempData, and then redirect to the action:

```
TempData["MyViewModelFromRedirect"] = viewModel;
```

And in your redirected action:

```
var ViewModel = (MyViewModel)TempData["MyViewModelFromRedirect"];
```